# Designing-Creating form in CMS for End User

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms

I am using Orchard CMS for the development. i need to give the functionality of creating forms to end user once deployed on their system. user should be able to create new fields and design the input form e.g. Registration and attach it to website.

I want to know if this is possible in Orchard CMS or any other good CMS system? i heard that designing forms is pretty related to designer and user will not be able to do it until he/she knows about some designing or programming?

Answer (score 0):

Orchard has a Custom Forms Module that easily allows a User to create their own Forms. Is it is not enough there are other modules which might help you.

Comment: Ok creating forms by user seems easy . What about using those fields in admin section inside module ? so if i am developing custom modules in orchard cms how i will have to integrate those fields with that?

Comment: Sorry, you must elaborate. What is exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: i have developed a module in Orchard CMS which will need fields from the forms which user will create dynamically after deployment. how could i integrate with these fields then?

Comment: Great description, not!. nevertheless, you might be able to get the data from the forms in tokens. Look for [http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-Custom-Forms](Custom Forms) and [http://devdirective.com/post/160/how-to-create-custom-forms-in-orchard-cms-with-email-and-recaptcha](Contact Form with Workflow) and [http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/extending-orchard-workflows-with-custom-activities](Extending Workflows). Then as always, looking at the source code helps a lot.